# Dependence of the existence of solutions to a first-order linear PDE on the initial conditions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have the following problem:

Show that there is no solution to the problem

$x\partial_tu+\partial_xu = 0 \\
u(x,0) = \sin(x)$,

but that there are infinitely many solutions to the problem

$x\partial_tu+\partial_xu = 0 \\
u(x,0) = \cos(x)$

I know that the method of characteristics cannot be used since the line $x =0$ is characteristic in the sense that all $(0, a)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is in $char_x(L)$, but other then that I have no clue on how to proceed. Any hints will be the most appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristics method works well: the charateristics curves for the second problem are:

$$\begin{cases}
 u=c_1\\
 x^2/2-t=c_2
\end{cases}$$

Being the general solution:

$$u=f(x^2/2-t)$$

with $f$ some function.

Imposig the initial conditions,

$$f(x^2/2)=\cos x$$

$$f(y)=\cos\sqrt{2y}$$

Then, the particular solution must fulfill the condition:

$$u(x,t)=\cos\sqrt{x^2-2t}$$

But observe that the square root is not defined for values such that $2t\gt x^2$. This gives us a hint about what's going on here. The characteristics are parabolas, $x^2/2-t=c_2$ for which $u$ is constant and the boundary conditions we are imposing ($u(x,0)=\cos x$) say nothing about the parabolas not crosing the $x$ axis, e.g. $x^2/2-t=-1$, so, we can give any value to $u$ along such parabolas and we will not contradict the initial conditions. Further, such arbitrary assignation for $u$ along that family of parabolas can be done in a continuous and differentiable way, so, there are infinitely many solutions.

I don't get why you say that the line $x=0$ is characteristic. It is not. In fact, the line along which the boundary conditions are given is not a characteristic curve, and this is a necessary condition for the problem to have a single solution, but as we can see, it is not suficient.

**Added**
The general solution for first problem would have to be very similar to the found for the second,

$$u(x,t)=\sin\sqrt{x^2-2t}$$

and it miss too determine the value of $u$ for curves with $2t\gt x^2$, but the point to consider here is different: the solution cannot be differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Consider the partial derivative along the line $x=0$ that, because the boundary conditions, for any solution it must coincide with the partial derivative for the function we have found:

$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right|_{x=0}=\frac{t\cos\sqrt{-2t}}{\sqrt{2}(-t)^{3/2}}$$

that is not defined at $t=0$.

Comment: +1, but that the "characteristic method works well" should be qualified: the key idea behind your argument is that the characteristics are _tangential_ to the initial curve $\{t = 0\}$ at $x = 0$; so for prescribed data for which $u_x(0,0) \neq 0$ there cannot be a compatible solution.

Comment: @WillieWong, you are right: the existence of such "lost" currves is the tangency at some point.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your time. According to Folland, a hypersurface $S$ is characteristic for the operator L at $x \in S$ if the normal vector $\nu(x)$ to $S$ ant $x$ is in $char_x(L)$. The hypersurface in question is where the initial conditions are defined, what means the line $t=0$. The normal unit vector to this is $(0, 1)$ at any point. Now, the characteristic form of the operator is $P(x, \xi) = \xi_x + x\xi_t \therefore P(x, \xi) = 0$ if and only if $ \xi_x = -x\xi_t$. So, note that at $(0,0) \in S$ we have that $\nu = (0, 1) \in char_x(L)$. So, $S$ is not non-characteristic.

Comment: Ok, that was the sense of "characteristic". Anyway, I intended make it intuitive, so is, to look at the problem from it's "back", so is, understand the way the problem is underdetermined: there are characteristic curves not crosing the curve where the values for $u$ are determined. Sincerely, this way is how I could make for me intuitive this kind of underdetermined problems. Interestingly this point of view leads to the condition of tangency between the line where the boundary conditions are established and the charcteristic curves (are underdetermined all "tangent" situations like this?)

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now.